# Adding Dynamic Tags to Elementor Form

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I need to be able to pull data from a page into a hidden form field on an Elementor Form. There are dynamic tags available but only Post Summary!

How can I add Post Title and any other field to the dynamic tags so they are available to be selected on the form?

Thanks,
Scott.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out how to do what I needed without Dynamic Tags using the function add_action('elementor_pro/forms/new_record', function($record, $handler) and using get_post_custom to retrieve data I needed.